# :active css class not working correctly to modify cursor property

Tags: css, hover, cursor, drag

I am trying to modify the cursor so it changes while I'm dragging (:active) the div/link.

However I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as the background property is working correctly.

```
div {cursor:crosshair;}
div:active {cursor:wait;}
a {cursor:crosshair;}
a:active {cursor:wait;}
```

As far as I understand, while the mouse is active (dragging) the :active properties should be applied. In this case, the background/color yellow property is being applied but the cursor property (wait) is not.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUGTw/)

Comment: can you tell what is the issue here..

Comment: because dragging and active both are different properties.for dragging which is not purely Cross-browser you can check this tutorial..http://www.jaycodesign.co.nz/css/cross-browser-css-grab-cursors-for-dragging/

Comment: From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active): `When interacting with a mouse, this is typically the time between the user presses the mouse button and releases it.` So technically clicking should change the server. Weird enough, it worked for me the first time, but now its not working. But on div, if you click and drag just a bit, like 1 step, then `cursor:wait` comes into action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cursor` does change to `wait` but on drag the `user-select` property also come into action which changes `cursor` to `text` by default.

You can disable it by doing:

```
div, a {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-all;
    -webkit-user-select: all;
    -ms-user-select: all;
    user-select: all;
}
```

The `w3c` property is currently not implemented by major-browsers. So you have to use vendor prefixes. A downside, and a major one, to this solution is that you won't be able to select the content inside elements `div` and `p` anymore. Mostly its used to make **`button`s** unselectable.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUGTw/1/)

But its still not working on `a`. Probably some other thing overriding it. Maybe the `HTTP request` handler? I don't know, I'm just throwing stupid ideas now.

[**+`user-select`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-css3-userint-19990916#user-select) (W3C)

Comment: Thanks, it works good enough for me, I don't mind neither if text is not selectable or if it does not work on links. However it would be nice to know how to "fix it" for the link also.